# Mongoose promise warning when updating a collection and saving an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update the School collection of different schools and push the new personid into an array of the collection. I keep getting an error message that two id's are the same. However, they are part of the array and are not the _id's of the doc. It fails when saving multiple people inside of a school.

What I see is that that specific School doc is totally deleted and two new id's are created inside a document with only the array of two personid's.
The person looks like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a4"),
 "name" : "Max",
 "schoolid" : ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a3"),
 "__v" : 0
}
```

I would like to have the schools look like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a3"),
 "people" : [ 
     ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a9"),
     ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a4"), -> Max ^
     ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a2")
 ],
 "schoolname" : "De manenschijn",
 "city" : "",
 "street" : "",
 "streetnumber" : "",
 "zipcode" : "",
 "__v" : 0
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
School.findByIdAndUpdate(schoolid,
  { "$push": { "people": personid}},
  { "upsert": true, "new": true })
  .exec(person.save());
```

The school now looks like this with the query failing:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a3"),
 "__v" : 0,
 "people" : [ 
     ObjectId("5bc4911536597f51522ab0a2") -> different from Max
 ]
}
```

My School looks like this:

```
const schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 schoolname : String,
 city : String,
 street : String,
 streetnumber : String,
 zipcode : String,
 people : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

My Person looks like this:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name : String,
 schoolid : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School' },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

What I also found is that the query is executed twice with the same id, so that might cause the err message, but still, the school doc is entirely deleted after the first update.

error message of mongo:

(node:86353) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: DB.schools index: *id* dup key: { : ObjectId('5bc4911536597f51522ab0ad') }

[0] (node:86353) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: It may not be the only problem, but `.exec(person.save())` is definitely an issue. This will call `save` and then pass the returned promise to `exec` which is expecting a callback instead.

Comment: Moving `person.save()` after closing `exec();` to a new line won't help. While debugging, I got 2 id's of the same guy in the `people` array, and for every other person two id's are added, even though the function should be only called once.

Comment: I think we'll need a [MCVE] to help further.

Comment: try changing the `type` of `people` to `array` in school schema